# How to bind ToggleButtons with a List?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a lot of ToggleButtons (about 260). Part of my code with ToggleButtons:

```
<ToggleButton Style="{DynamicResource Seat}" Content="10" Click="OnSeatButtonClick"/>
<ToggleButton Style="{DynamicResource Seat}" Content="18" Click="OnSeatButtonClick"/>
<ToggleButton Style="{DynamicResource Seat}" Content="10" Click="OnSeatButtonClick" IsEnabled="False"/>
```

I want to add action that after clicking on button "Confirm changes", ToggleButtons that are at the moment checked will go into disabled state. And what is more I want those changes to be saved to database.

So I figured that I would need to add some unique id to those ToggleButtons. And then somehow bind them to a List with elements of type Saet.

Code of class Seat:

```
public class Seat
{
    string Column;
    string Number;
    bool IsTaken;
}
```

So my **question** is: how to bind those ToggleButtons with List, so that I will be able to operate on them?

Any help here much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) and set its [`ItemTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) to be your `ToggleButton`, bind the [`ItemsSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) to your seat-collection. From there its just some custom logic in the handler.

It would probably be advantageous to provide properties for the button-state in your bound object as, then you can bind the `IsEnabled` and `IsChecked` to those.