# How to change ToggleButton property IsEnabled from codebehind?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I want to set property `IsEnabled` to `False` for some `ToggleButton` after user click on ConfirmButton. I would like to do it from codebehind in OnMarkTakenSeatsClick action.

Some of my ToggleButtons look like that:

```
<ToggleButton Style="{DynamicResource Seat}" x:Name="A10" Content="10" Click="OnSeatButtonClick" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28.404" Margin="594.623,219.36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="29.145"/>
```

I have list of objects (seats) that have ToggleButtons names that should be disabled. My Click action from ConfirmButton looks like that:

```
void OnMarkTakenSeatsClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Seat addedSeat in seats)
            {
                if (addedSeat.IsSelected)
                { 

                }
            }
        }
```

Any help here much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using you have name in a `String` inside some property of `Seat` object. You can use algorithm given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/wpf-ways-to-find-controls) to find any control via name. Once you have the control you can disable it easily by setting `IsEnabled = false`

Answer (score 1):

This is why i said that it would be good to have respective properties on your seats [in your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243506/how-to-bind-togglebuttons-with-a-list), then you can just bind the `IsEnabled` of the button to that and in your handler logic you do not need any reference to the ui at all, just set the property to `false` and that is it.